# convert time to WordPress user's local time

Tags: date, date-time

i saved SERVER time manually for specific options...
i want them to convert to user-specific time for site (the time that is set in GENERAL OPTIONS).

for example, i want `141234567890` to be converted in like this: `13:25:57 20-05-2016`

`the_date` and such functions are only for post...

Answer (score 2):

The correct function to use for what you describe would be [`date_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) WordPress function.

It will produce output that is correct for timezone configured in WordPress and also localized if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

found WP built-in function  [`get_date_from_gmt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_date_from_gmt) :

`get_date_from_gmt('13:49:18 26/05/2016')`
or

`get_date_from_gmt(strtotime('13:49:18 26/05/2016'))`